# Old switch case to C# 8.0: Switch Expressions

Tags: c#

I have this switch on a Foreach.
I use an EnumerateFiles to list files in various directories and use the Switch case to handle them according to directories.

The string [] keys are the names of directories.

I'm curious how it would look in C # 8.0: Switch Expressions.
With switch expressions I could put other patterns.

Would someone help me?

```
string[] keys = new string[] { "kernel", "btl", "cloudsave", "event", "msb", "dcp" };

            switch (keys.FirstOrDefault(s => filePath.Contains(s)))
            {
                case "btl":
                case "cloudsave":
                case "event":
                case "msb":
                    ToolWrapper.FFXTool(args: $"-e -t \"{FileLocationInfo.Table}\" \"{filePath}\" \"{GetTextPath(filePath)}\"",
                                        tool: FileLocationInfo.FFxdlg);
                    break;
                case "kernel":
                    ToolWrapper.FFXTool(args: $"-e -t \"{FileLocationInfo.Table}\" \"{filePath}\" \"{GetTextPath(filePath)}\"",
                                        tool: FileLocationInfo.FFx2mt);
                    break;
                case "dcp":
                    string _file = $"{Path.GetDirectoryName(GetTextPath(filePath))}{"\\"}{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath)}";

                    ToolWrapper.FFXTool(args: $"4 -s -f -min 0x40 \"{filePath}\" \"{_file}\"",
                                        tool: FileLocationInfo.FFxsplit);

                    _ = Parallel.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(GetTextPath(filePath)), "macrodic*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                                                                                            .Where(f => Regex.IsMatch(f, pattern: @"\.00[0123456]$")), file =>
                    {
                        _folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
                        ToolWrapper.FFXTool(args: $"-e -t \"{FileLocationInfo.Table}\" \"{file}\" \"{$@"{file}.txt"}\"", tool: FileLocationInfo.FFxdlg);
                    });
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

This particular switch statement should not be turned into a switch expression. Not every switch statement should be translated into a switch expression.

In a switch expression, each case *evaluates to a certain value*, but in the switch statement shown, you can't really associate a single value with each case, especially not with the `dcp` case, where you do something drastically different than every other case.

Here is an example of a switch statement which is *suitable* for turning into a switch expression:

```
switch (variable) {
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine("Message A");
        break;
    case 2:
        Console.WriteLine("Message B");
        break;
    case 3:
        Console.WriteLine("Message B");
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Default Message");
        break;
}
```

Each case kind of has a value associated with it, doesn't it?

The switch expression would look like:

```
var stringToPrint = variable switch {
    1 => "Message A",
    2 => "Message B",
    3 => "Message C",
    _ => "Default Message"
};
Console.WriteLine(stringToPrint);
```

---

I guess you *could* turn every one of your cases into an `Action`, and at the end invoke that action, but that's overkill.

Comment: The switch is reading a string with the directory address and using .Contains to determine the case.
If the address contains the directory 'btl' it does something. If it contains kernel it does something else.

At the time this was the solution I found to treat the kernel and dcp directory where I need to do something different. It was switch case or if else.

I would be grateful if anyone has a better idea to handle this case.

Comment: @RhadamantsTriboGamer what’s wrong with a switch statement? You are not supposed to change every switch statement into the new switch expression. The new feature is only useful for a few situations.

Comment: A switch Expression you can image as a Dictionary, that you need only in one spot.
You do a Key-Value Association.  Not a Key-Action Association.